# How do you create libs from 2 maven builds with the same name?

Tags: architecture, maven, build, 64-bit, 32-bit

I need to create 2 libraries, a 32 and a 64 bit library, with the same name.  I would like to do this in one build in maven however I don't see a way that it is possible.

I have tried to do this with modules however the project gets confused on setting the artifactId to the module name and passing that in by default to various things such as the MSVC compiler, linker and manifest.

I have also tried to do this in two different executions however I can not dump the 64 bit object definitions into a file for the manifest to read without also including the 32 bit objects that the linker came up with in the previous build.

Has anyone done multiple builds that produce two files with the same name, placed into different directories?  or does anyone have any ideas on how this can be done?

Comment: you would use `profiles` to do this

Comment: I think Maven's whole point that it does not produce different artifacts with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "same name" I read that as same groupId and artifactId. Single Maven module can produce more than one artifact with same groupId and artifactId, but with different classifier. You can use [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) for that. Define [assembly descriptors](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html) one for each artifact, give assembly descriptors different IDs (e.g x32 and x64), those IDs will be used as artifact classifiers, and then define in your pom [assembly:single mojo](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html) [execution](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html#Execution%3a_Building_an_Assembly) [configured with those two assembly descriptors](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html#descriptors).